# Confusing about impedance termination

Tags: transmission-line, dds

Datasheets by analog devices state that I must terminate IC (AD9910) impedance by input impedance of 50 Ω and placement near the balun.

[image]

But here is the deal when I was looking for AD9912 datasheet (and others people project) I found that they using 100 Ω for termination and also place at IC pin instead of balun.

Impedance of these 2 ICs are identical.
[image]

Which is right? I'm so confused right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As the AD991x is a high input impedance, you need to drive it with a VOLTAGE, at its PINS.
2. If you are driving it as in the second figure of fig 32, from a SINGLE ENDED 50 Ω impedance source, through a balun, then that source, the balun, and the cable between them, all need to be terminated in 50 Ω. The AD991x can then sense the voltage across that terminating resistor on its pins.
3. If you are driving it as in figure 36 from a SOURCE with DIFF OUTPUTS, then you need to know that most differential output sources have two complementary outputs, EACH having a 50 Ω output impedance. Its total output impedance from pole to pole is therefore 100 Ω. This source therefore needs to be terminated in 100 Ω. That shown is a differential termination. You could equally well have a 50 Ω resistor from each output to ground.
4. In summary, both figures are correct. Terminate the signal source as it needs to be terminated, ignoring the AD991x. Sense the voltage across the termination with the AD991x, ignoring the source details.

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet does not say what you claim. Nowhere it says it must be terminated with 50 ohm, it says exactly opposite.

It says the termination can be chosen to be the same as signal source.

The termination should be 50 ohms or 100 ohms depending on what the signal source expects.

Comment: so lets assume i use balun for matching network with output 50 ohms , so i can terminate impedance by 50 ohms like in the first picture? since in the second picture they are not using balun thus it is not 50ohm

Comment: This is going in circles. The balun is for converting a 50 ohm single ended source into differential and so it still has 50 termination because balun used does not convert impedance. You can freely change your balun to convert impedance too if you want. The last picture has 100 ohm termination because the source and transmission line already have 100 ohm impedance and they are balanced. Yes if you use balun with whatever input impedance you want and if it has 50 ohm output then you need to terminate with 50 ohms.